# Any framework/ tool available out there to automate iPhone native applications without using application's source code?

Tags: iphone, ios-ui-automation

Frank is good, however, it requires the application's source code. And so do the others. For example, square/ KIF, Telerik, UIAutomation etc.

I am not considering Fonemonkey. I am looking for something analogous to "Robotium for Android" which lets you do the scripting in Eclipse by re-signing the .apk file and can work without application's source code.

I believe this is very important since, in a work environment, a developer will not necessarily share the source code of the application unless it is an open source app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use instruments tool (which is inbuilt in xcode), which does not require app's source code.